# pandas syntax error

Tags: pandas, data, test, split

8 de python y la versión 1.0.5 de pandas. Actualmente estoy aprendiendo a hacer análisis estadísticos con Python y con el código:

```
`{import pandas as pd
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   from sklearn import linear_model
   from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

   data = 'C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/PROYECTOS DE PYTHON/DATA SCIENCE AVANZADO/DATA SCIENTIST PARA 
   PYTHON/base_datos_2008.cvs'

   df = data.dropna(subset = ["ArrDelay"])
   df = df.sample(frac=1).head(1000)

   X = df[['AirTime', 'Distance', 'DepDelay']]
   Y = df['ArrDelay']

   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y test_size=.2, random_state = 10)

   regrINTERNA = linear_model.LinearRegression()
   regrINTERNA.fit(X, Y)
   prediccionesINTERNA = regrINTERNA.predict(X)
   print("R2: ", r2_score(Y, prediccionesINTERNA))

   File "c:/Users/DELL/Desktop/PROYECTOS DE PYTHON/DATA SCIENCE AVANZADO/DATA SCIENTIST PARA 
   PYTHON/Validacion externa en Python.py", line 14
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y test_size=.2, random_state = 10)
                                                            ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax}`
```

Segun yo la dirección de donde esta la base de datos esta correcta, el error se encuentra en el renglón X_train...etc.

Answer (score 0):

tenes un error de sintaxist (casi siempre de que escribiste mal algo o te falto algo) en la linea 14.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y test_size=.2, random_state = 10)
```

Despues de los parámetros X e Y te falta una coma (",")

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=.2, random_state = 10)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, soy completamente nuevo en el lenguaje.

Comment: Ahora tengo otro error me dice: df = data.dropna(subset = ['ArrDelay'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dropna'